# What is the difference VirtualService and Gateway in istio?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I am trying to understand the difference between the VirtualService and the Gateway in istio? As far I could understand, VirutalService is also used for the purpose of routing the traffic same as Gateway

Comment: You would say what's the "exact" difference between red oranges and grapefruit, but you wouldn't say that with apples and pears, because they are a completely different fruit. So, there is no "exact" difference between a `Gateway` and a `VirtualService`. They are completely different objects. Just read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Suren. Updated the question as per the suggestion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to istio documentation:

> A [`VirtualService`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) defines a set of traffic routing rules to apply when a host is addressed. Each routing rule defines matching criteria for traffic of a specific protocol. If the traffic is matched, then it is sent to a named destination service (or subset/version of it) defined in the registry.

> [`Gateway`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) describes a load balancer operating at the edge of the mesh receiving incoming or outgoing HTTP/TCP connections. The specification describes a set of ports that should be exposed, the type of protocol to use, SNI configuration for the load balancer, etc.

`Gateway` is generally used to expose a `VirtualService` to the outside world. So with this object we can control how and which traffic from outside will reach one of our `VirtualServices`. It is also possible to specify how `Gateway` treats the traffic, E.g. [TLS termination](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/) or [SNI passthrough](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/).

There are some configurations that are possible only when both `Gateway` and `VirtualService` work together.

In short `Gateway` is for external traffic while `VirtualService` is for traffic that is already inside the istio cluster.